# Expand CSS3 animation is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I have a very simplistic overlay navigation, see below:

```
<nav role="navigation" class="navigation">
    <a href="#" class="brand-logo"><img src="img/beer-jug-logo.png" alt="brand logo"></a>
    <ul class="navigation-list">
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Design</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Interiors</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a class="close"></a>
</nav>
```

Now I have added a very simple CSS expand and shrink animation  and these animations are toggled using jQuery. The animations code are below:

```
.navigation.shrinkMenu {
    -webkit-animation-name: shrinkMenu;
    -o-animation-name: shrinkMenu;
    animation-name: shrinkMenu;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -o-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}
.navigation.expandMenu {
    -webkit-animation-name: expandMenu;
    -o-animation-name: expandMenu;
    animation-name: expandMenu;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
    -o-animation-delay: 3s;
    animation-delay: 3s;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -o-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}
@keyframes  shrinkMenu {
    90% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    99%  {
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        bottom: 50%;
        right: 50%;
    }
    100%  {
        opacity: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        bottom: 50%;
        right: 50%;
    }
}
@keyframes expandMenu {
    0%  {
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        bottom: 50%;
        right: 50%;
    }
    100%  {
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
}
```

The initial styles on the menu are below:

```
.navigation  {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    /*background: rgba(244 ,41, 65,.9);*/
    background: rgba(255 ,255, 255,.9);
    display: flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    flex-direction:column;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

The jQuery code to toggle the menu visibility is below:

```
$('.close').on('click', function() {
    $('.navigation').addClass('shrinkMenu');
});
$('.H-menu').on('click', function() {
    $('.navigation').addClass('expandMenu');
});
```

**[FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/Lue7am06/1/)**

Now if you see the fiddle or even run the animation in Chrome or FF you'll notice that the shrink animation works just fine, but the expand animation is abrupt, I.E. it just doesn't work. Can anybody please explain why the animation is not working?

Comment: Why do you have `-o-` prefixes? `-ms-` and `-moz-` would be understandable (unnecessary though), but just `-webkit-` and `-o-` is a strange thing. However, could you simply try to put your 'initial' values into the `0%` of your animation? Because 0% does  _not_ hold the 'default' (cf. actual element) values, so it would make sense if the first time it seems to work right, but then when you reverse it it won't go back to your initial values, it will go to the earliest values in the animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Note:** This doesn't seem to be consistent problem. The problem happens in Fiddle only when it is loaded for the first time (by giving the URL in the address bar and clicking Go). When any edit is made to the Fiddle and we just "Run" it, the error does not happen. I could not re-create the issue in Stack Snippet either.

There are no problems with your animation code or the CSS. The problem seems to be due to `href` attribute in the `a.H-menu` tag. When this attribute is specified and there is no value, it seems like the whole page is getting reloaded on the click of the menu icon and thus you don't get to see animation.

You could do one of the following things:

- Set `href='#'` and use `e.preventDefault()` within the click event handler (or)
- Don't even mention the `href` attribute in the `a.H-menu` tag.

Doing either of the above would mean that the page won't be reloaded and hence animation will get displayed.

---

You could verify what I am saying by visiting the following Fiddles (view the console on first load):

- [Fiddle with original code](https://jsfiddle.net/Lue7am06/4/) - Open the Fiddle and open the Console immediately. Error message indicating that the image (beer-jug-logo.png) could not be loaded would be displayed. Clear this error message, close the menu and click the icon to re-open it. You would notice that the error gets displayed again (indicating that it is getting re-loaded).
- [Fiddle with href='#'](https://jsfiddle.net/Lue7am06/6/) - Do same steps as above and you'd notice the animation working properly and that there is no error message in the console upon clicking the `.H-menu` icon.
- [Fiddle with no href](https://jsfiddle.net/Lue7am06/5/) - Same steps and you'd notice same result as the second Fiddle.

Comment: haha you almost documented the problem :D thanks buddy .. can't beleive it ended up being such a silly mistake :P

Comment: I was stumped when I was looking into it at first @AlexanderSolonik. Every time I make some dummy change (like adding a border) it started working and I was like *what, why does that change have any impact on the animation*. So, I had to create a few fiddles to finally figure it out :)